# Jetpack Compose - Should modifier parameter be applied to the outer / top most view only?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In jetpack compose, when passing a modifier into my composable, should the modifier be applied only to the outer most view, or all of the subviews as well?

Here's a quick example:

```
fun SomeComposable(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(modifier = modifier) {
        Text(modifier = modifier.extraModifiersIfNeeded(), text = "Text")
        Text(modifier = modifier.extraModifiersIfNeeded(), text = "Text")
        Text(modifier = modifier.extraModifiersIfNeeded(), text = "Text")
    }
}
```

I would initially assume this is incorrect, because any modifier passed into SomeComposable would also change all of the subviews.

Are there any documentations making this very clear? Can I please have a link to any documentations?

Thank you!

Comment: The modifier does not have to be passed at all. If you pass it, then you need it for some reason, in a top-level function or lower, it's up to you.

Comment: Doesn't directly answer the question but - you should use `composedOf` for modifiers that are reused.  And yes, only the top level composable would be passing in `modifier` which could then continue to add to that modifier as necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you pass a modifier to a composable, it should be elevated to the highest level that makes sense for your use case. This is because you could have unintended side effects say when you apply padding to your example. The `Column` will have the padding applied to its contents, but then there would be additional padding to each `Text` composable.

This [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/modifiers#extracting_and_reusing_scoped_modifiers) says to "extract them to the highest level possible".

Comment: Exactly, But it should be optional anyways.

Answer (score 0):

First , `modifier` is applied (explicitly) only to those `composable` functions which needs those modifications.

We pass the `modifier` to outermost `composable` to make our `composable` function more robust and reusable.